# Чем вызвана ошибка incompatible types 'Integer' and 'TCaption'?

Tags: delphi

```
var Bukavkes: array [32..255] of integer;

procedure ShowResults(Memo: TMemo);
 var i: integer;
begin
 for i := Low(Bukavkes) to High(Bukavkes) do
 if Chr(i) in ['A'..'z', 'À'..'ÿ', '0'..'9', ' '] then
 Memo.Lines.Add(Chr(i) + ': ' + IntToStr(Bukavkes[i]));
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
 var i: integer;
begin
 for i := Low(Bukavkes) to High(Bukavkes) do Bukavkes[i] := 0;
end;

procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
 var i: integer;
begin
 for i := 1 to TMemo1.Text do
 if Ord(TMemo1.Text[i]) >= 32 then inc(Bukavkes[Ord(TMemo1.Text[i])]);
 ShowResults(TMemo2);
end;
```

Ошибка на четвертой снизу строке.

Comment: > `for i := 1 to TMemo1.Text do`

Как вы себе представляете цикл *"от одного до содержимого TMemo1"* ?

Comment: интересно, чем ТС умудрился так слить свою карму, учитывая, что задал он лишь три вопроса?

Comment: @DreamChild, тревоги сразу много сливают.

Comment: я знаю, но я специально сейчас посмотрел - его никто не "тревожил" вроде

Comment: @DreamChild, там удаленные вопросы в массе.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Не `TMemo1`, а `Memo1`...
Надо так:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
  var i: integer;
begin
  for i := 1 to Length(Memo1.Text) do
    if Ord(Memo1.Text[i]) >= 32 then inc(Bukavkes[Ord(Memo1.Text[i])]);
  ShowResults(Memo2);
end;
```

Comment: Спасибо! Корректнее работает если Length(Memo1.Text) не -1 а +1

Comment: @Yura Ivanov

    for i := 1 to Length(Memo1.Text) do

Символы в строке от 1 нумеруются же!

Comment: @kot-da-vinci, зарапортовался. да. спасибо, поправил.